# Go back to rectangular buttons on profile page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

I know this is fairly opinionated and conservative, but recently Stack Overflow changed the "Questions" "Answers" "Summary" etc. buttons to be circular. Same with "Profile" "Edit profile and settings" etc. I believe that this is out of place with the square and straight search bar and top-right corner buttons. 
I think that SO should rollback to the previous interface which looked a lot better. I also don't like the orange background color.

**Reasons**

- Looks better
- Using circular buttons is a bandwagon thing and Stack Overflow is not a bandwagon
- Consistency

We should do a poll from the community about which they like better.

Comment: Why? “Looks better” is extremely subjective. Can you come up with a better motivation?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Stack Overflow is not expected to take the bandwagon

Comment: "We should do a poll" in your reasons to roll back implies that you think that the poll will be in favour of how it used to be.

Comment: I'm not convinced how "design by polling" is in any way better than this "bandwagon" thing you mention.

Comment: Yeah square buttons. But don't throw the old ones away after the reversion. I want my name in a cartouche.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My problem with this request is that it doesn’t fix anything. It’s not:

- A bug
- A request for a new feature
- An accessibility issue
- A usability issue
- A consistency issue
  (For example, a button somehow appearing differently on different pages where that’s clearly not supposed to happen.)

The buttons aren’t broken, in the wrong place, unreadable or unclear, or unreachable at certain screen sizes. The request wouldn’t make them easier to find or use or improve their functionality in any way.

I don’t think it’s a good use of time.